# Native ActionBar with tabs and spinners?

Tags: android

I am new in Android programming. I want to build an Android 4.0+ app, and I want to use the native ActionBar, tabs and spinner controls.
Is possible to use tabs and spinners at the same time in native ActionBar?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to use tabs and spinners at the same time in native ActionBar?

Assuming that you mean "action bar tabs", then they cannot directly be used at the same time, as they are both considered navigation modes. Moreover, since action bar tabs can be converted into drop-down list (i.e., spinner) navigation by the framework, having two spinners is likely to be confusing.

I would recommend using an alternative tab implementation, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator.